# d3 tree - Limit number of nodes returned from search

Tags: d3.js

I want to limit the number of leaf nodes returned from a search on the tree, so that the returned tree is not overly cluttered.

Search node label:

```
        $( "#searchText" ).on( 'keyup', function ( e ) {
            if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
                clearAll( root );
                expandAll( root );
                update( root );
                searchField = "d.name";
                searchText = e.target.value;
                //console.log(searchText);
                searchTree( root );
                root.children.forEach( collapseAllNotFound );
                update( root );
            }
        } );
```

and the search function on the tree is:

```
    function searchTree( d ) {
        if ( d.children )
            d.children.forEach( searchTree );
        else if ( d._children )
            d._children.forEach( searchTree );
        var searchFieldValue = eval( searchField );
        if ( searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.toLowerCase().match( searchText.toLowerCase() ) ) {
            // Walk parent chain
            var ancestors = [];
            var parent = d;
            while ( typeof ( parent ) !== "undefined" ) {
                ancestors.push( parent );
                //console.log(parent);
                parent.class = "found";
                parent = parent.parent;
            }
            //console.log(ancestors);
        }
    }
```

As an example, in the fiddle link below, there are 32 child nodes with a label that contains "Mary", e.g. "Mary x".

If the number of returned nodes is say, greater than 20, then the tree remains collapsed and display an alert "Too many matching nodes.  Refine your search terms."  Else 20 or less nodes from search then expand the tree to show the nodes.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjprfc56/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add count search resul function  like below

```
function getSimilarLeafCnt(d, countSum=0) {
   if ( d.children ) {
        countSum = d.children.reduce( (m,d)=>{return getSimilarLeafCnt(d,m);} , countSum);
    }else if ( d._children ){
        countSum = d._children.reduce( (m,d)=>{return getSimilarLeafCnt(d,m);} , countSum);
    }

    var searchFieldValue = eval( searchField );
    if ( searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.toLowerCase().match( searchText.toLowerCase() ) ) {
        countSum++
    }
    return countSum
}
```

and call it before search

```
...
console.log(getSimilarLeafCnt(root))
if( getSimilarLeafCnt(root)) > 20) {
    alert('too many results!')
}else {
    searchTree( root );
}..
```

working example here https://jsfiddle.net/7vg8hpd2/

Comment: Looks OK but I can't get this to work.  Can you put this into a fork of my fiddle please?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 add fiddle url in answer!